# What is an SBT resolver?

Tags: scala, sbt

There are a lot of questions and guides about *how* to include SBT resolver to a project, but still there are no info about *what* is an SBT resolver and how can it help including dependencies to a project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

sbt resolver is the configuration for repository that contains jars and their dependencies
for example the below is a resolver definition for a repository called Sonatype  and it points at snapshot releases (dev versions)

```
resolvers += 
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

When you specify a dependncy in sbt (or any other build system for that matter) the build system needs to know where to look to find that dependency. in JVM world a lot of dependencies are stored in the default maven2 repo ( https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) but sometimes you need to use other custom repositories and you'd define add a resolver for that

Comment: But how can I use this dependency after I added it to resolvers?

Comment: For example, I added 
resolvers += "brotli" at "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/brotli/"

How can I use brotli lib after that?

Comment: That's a dependency not a resolver and you'd add that with libraryDependencies += "org.brotli" % "dec" % "0.1.2" or something similar. You can search maven central for dependencies (most will be there) e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.brotli/dec/0.1.2